# TableView with TabBar using functions to reload de table without new ViewControllers

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, core-data, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `TableView` managed with `CoreData` and `NSFetchedResultController`. I want to add a `TabBar` to my `TableView` and add some items like: favourites, search and something else. Do I need a `ViewController` for each item? or Could I add each Item to a function in the tableViewController and manage the fetch queries there and reload the Table with the new fetch query?

Is this better to be manageg with  a ToolBar instead of a TabBar?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a `UITabBarController` as it works with an array of child `ViewController`s. You can write a custom container controller (more work), but I'd first read through the docs to get a better handle on how it operates and see if that's what you really want.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html